# why does ubuntu 11.10 take so much of power?

Tags: battery

I have a DELL XPS laptop. It works for almost 3.5 hours while running windows but while running ubuntu11.10 the power lasts for only 1 hour. Is there something odd in the OS??

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem that is supposed to be solved with Ubuntu 12.04.

Meanwhile you can use Jupiter. It will help you in reducing overheating and increased batter  life:

For more Info: 
http://www.computerandyou.net/2012/03/how-to-install-jupiter-in-linux-mint-and-ubuntu-to-fix-over-heating-issue/

Comment: Could you please add a reference on being solved in 12.04?

Comment: In addition to abhishek information, the following link explains the usage of Jupiter application.             http://www.auroraos.org/project/jupiter

Comment: @zpletan Ubuntu 12.04 is Long Term Support release.. and as history suggests LTS versions have always been better in terms of performance...Just hoping that it would be better with 12.04 :)